# bootstrap popover - div disappears on mouse movement

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I'm using bootstrap popover where my div appears correctly on mouse over. However the div disappears when I move the mouse. Here is the code. I want the div to stay unless user clicks somewhere else.

```
<div rel="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-placement="top" data-original-title="<h4>Deceased & Informant</h4>" data-content="'.$content.'" data-html="true">data
```

I found a related jsfiddle [example](http://jsfiddle.net/9P64a/) to explain the problem better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `manual` trigger and write your own event handlers to do what you want.

In the below, I'm using JQuery to show the popover on the next `mouseenter` event, and then on any click in the document, I'm hiding the popover and resetting the event handler for the next `mouseenter` event.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#popoverData').one('mouseenter', function() {
    $(this).popover('show');
  });

  $(document).on('click', function() {
    $('#popoverData').popover('hide');
    $('#popoverData').one('mouseenter', function() {
      $(this).popover('show');
    });
  });
});
```

```css
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.container {
    margin: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.0/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">

    <a id="popoverData" class="btn" href="#" data-content="Popover with manual data-trigger" rel="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Title" data-trigger="manual">Popover with manual data-trigger</a>
    
</div>
```

Here is a jsfiddle of the same: http://jsfiddle.net/a8kamz92/

#### Update

Here's an example showing how to apply the same logic to multiple popovers. The basic premise is to use a JQuery selector that matches more than one popover. This is just an example of one way to match multiple popovers; more specific selectors can be used to suit your needs.

```js
$(function() {
  var popoversSelector = '.has-popover div[rel=popover]';

  $(popoversSelector).one('mouseenter', function() {
    $(this).popover('show');
  });

  $(document).on('click', function() {
    var popovers = $(popoversSelector);

    popovers.popover('hide');
    popovers.one('mouseenter', function() {
      $(this).popover('show');
    });
  });
});
```

```css
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.container {
    margin: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.0/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="has-popover">
      <div rel="popover"
           data-trigger="manual"
           data-placement="bottom"
           data-original-title="Informant"
           data-content="content"
           data-html="true">
             January
      </div>
    </td>
    
    <td class="has-popover">
      <div rel="popover"
           data-trigger="manual"
           data-placement="bottom"
           data-original-title="Informant"
           data-content="content"
           data-html="true">
             $100
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here's the jsfiddle as well: http://jsfiddle.net/erv5ssoy/

Comment: this is good. thanks :). I need some more advice. My div is actually a row data, which means I cannot assign same id to every row data. Second, the data that I am showing on hover, is another small div/table which has multiple tabs inside, so I want it to disappear when mouse is away from that div/table, not on click. take  a look here http://jsfiddle.net/uwxrhk3j/1/

Comment: One thing you can try is to just use a JQuery selector that applies to all popovers, rather than by id. From your example, your selector could be `".has-popover div[rel=popover]"`, which will match all popovers in your table cells with the `has-popover` class, and then use the same logic as in my answer. Here's the jsfiddle for it: http://jsfiddle.net/erv5ssoy/

Comment: For the part on disappearing on a different trigger (in your case, `mouseleave` from the popover) you should update your question or ask another one, as your original question asks how to make the popover disappear when the user clicks elsewhere. It's possible to do what you want, but I think it'll complicate things to try 2 contradictory solutions in one answer.

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle to get you started on your 2nd question: http://jsfiddle.net/0ojn2ror/. If my answer helped for your original question, I'd appreciate an accept :)

Comment: Great !! It works. I appreciate all the details and working examples.